# config Spyder or Pycharm to comply with the PEP8 style standards

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder, pep8, autoformatting

I use spyder to code python. Could you guide me to set up spyder or Pycharm or  config to comply with the PEP8 style standards, autoformat.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your own config than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PyCharm 2.7 takes care of readability and general beauty of your code.

Now it supports continuous checking of your code for PEP 8 compliance on the fly, as you type it in the editor. PyCharm highlights any coding style violations and gives you suggestions, which you can apply instantly with the well known PyCharm quick-fixes (PEP8 guidline is to be found [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?)))

> Autoformat Code:

To reformat code for the current file, follow these steps: In the editor of the currently opened file, press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L` . Note that if you select Code. Reformat Code from the main menu or press `Ctrl+Alt+L` , PyCharm will try to reformat the source code automatically without opening the Reformat File dialog.

Comment: Spyder and Pycharm only show warnings, not autoformat when we save. I did Java before, eclipse automatically format while I'm writting codes. How can config it? Thanks